# Mirth custom web service

Tags: java, web-services, mirth

I have made a custom web service in Java just like the one described [on the Mirth wiki](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/wiki/display/mirth/Creating+a+custom+Web+Service+in+Mirth+Connect+3.0.1)

There are few methods defined in the web service class, but I don't know how to configure Mirth to listen to different methods of a single web service. Are there any tutorials on this matter? How do I define different input and output data for different methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@javax.jws.WebMethod` and `@javax.jws.WebParam` annotations in your class that extends `AcceptMessage`, and your return value can be any class that you've appropriately decorated as XML. Something like:

```
package mypackage.myservices;

import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import com.mirth.connect.connectors.ws.AcceptMessage;
import com.mirth.connect.connectors.ws.WebServiceReceiver;

@WebService
public class QueryService extends AcceptMessage {

    public QueryService(WebServiceReceiver webServiceReceiver) {
        super(webServiceReceiver);
    }

    @WebMethod(action="Authenticate")
    public AuthResponse authenticate(@WebParam(name="Username") String username, 
        @WebParam(name="Password") String password) {
        //authenticate your user and return an AuthResponse, 
        //possibly containing a token for use in subsequent calls...

        return new AuthResponse();
    }

    @WebMethod(action="GetResponse")
    public QueryResponse getResponse(@WebParam(name="QueryObject") Query query) {
        //handle the Query object, use it to get data from a DB, or whatever

        return new QueryResponse(); // or an appropriate Response object
    }
}
```

Where your `AuthResponse`, `Query` and `QueryResponse` objects can be any appropriately decorated (with `java.xml.bind.annotation...`) objects you like. Your methods will then be described in the WSDL (which Mirth gives you the address of in the Connector), so your service can be consumed by third parties.